# Mecurial version control, setting up: 'hg init'

Tags: version-control, tortoisehg

I'm trying to set up Mecurial version control following [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-version-control-with-unity3d--mobile-12304) tutorial. But my question is about simply installing the program in the first place. Once I install, I should be able to type 'hg init', and this will create a repository folder. But this creates it in the default directory of "C:\WINDOWS\system32", which is understandable. So, am I supposed to install the program in the directory that I want the repository to be in? It's so confusing, because in the tutorial, they use these commands without mentioning changing the directory or anything, and don't mention installing in the targetted folder. So I'm confused about where I need to install, and what I need to prefix in cmd to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to install TortoiseHg with Windows Explorer "shell" integration. Than you will have better integration in Windows.
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download

Anyway you can install Mercurial to default directory. It will add hg to PATH variabe. Than you can use command hg in any directory.
http://hginit.com/01.html

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to use better manuals for RTFMing ([Mercurial Kick Start](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/) from aragost Trifork is good brain-powered alternative, not dumb "do *this* and *this*...") or read noted manual (and help-texts) and help carefully and understand, what you done.

Manual have such sentence:

> The first thing we need to do is give our project folder a repository.
>
> On the command line enter:     `hg init`

which, in *correctly expanded* version will be: "After switching to directory, which already have  project and where you want to have repository..."

but you ignored this (obvious after `hg help init`) thing and just jump to command-prompt to *some strange place* (by default `cmd.exe` have `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` as stating point) and **`hg init` without parameter** create repository in **current directory**, as expected and written in doc

```
>cd
z:\

>hg init SomeRepo

>cd SomeRepo

>hg id
000000000000 tip
```